# Dash plotly chart with weekly price range and volume net as bars on either side of range

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly, plotly-dash

Can someone please help me how to plot the following graph in dash plotly?

[image]

```
import pandas as pd

# Create a sample dataset
data = {
    'DateTime':['2022-01-01', '2022-01-02', '2022-01-03', '2022-01-04', '2022-01-05']
    'Price': [10.2, 9.8, 11.5, 10.9, 12.1],
    'Volume': [100, 150, 200, 120, 180]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Comment: In such a case, the dumbbell graph in the graph gallery seems like it could be useful. See [this](https://plotly.com/python/dumbbell-plots/#basic-dumbbell-plot) for more information.